# MOSS 2007 standard workflow

Tags: 2007, workflow-activity

Is there anyway to a user with permission to start a workflow on all existing in a library over again? I mean not only when new item is created or changed, but in my case it's sometimes needed just to start the standard Approval workflow attached to a document library so that all of the existing documents gets approved again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way I know to accomplish this with out going to every single item, would be via custom code. Is that an option?

Comment: I would definitely go for the code, but our customer seeks for a standard solution.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a "standard" solution for this. But, it also depends on your definition of "standard."

The only non-code way to do something like this that I know of is to use a complex set of Sharepoint Designer workflows to create a loop that will go through and initiate the workflow on all Items. See the reference for loops in SPD [here](http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-looping-workflow-how-to-loop.html).

**A better way** would be to use the SPServices plugin to retreive all the items in the list using [getListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists) and then starting the desired workflow using [StartWorkflow](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StartWorkflow).

**Another Theoretical way** would be to require content approval on the particular library and use manage site content and structure or SPD to mass check-out and check-in all the documents thus starting the content approval workflow.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the comment dude :-) Let me check this and get back to you..